# BigQuery Storage Write / managedwriter api return error server_shutting_down

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api, google-api-client

As we know, the [advantage of BigQuery Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api#advantages), one month ago, we replace `insertAll` with managedwriter API on our server. It seems to work well for one month, however, we met the following errors recently

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = closing transport due to: connection error: 
desc = "error reading from server: EOF", received prior goaway: code: NO_ERROR, 
debug data: "server_shutting_down"
```

The version of managedwriter API are:

```
cloud.google.com/go/bigquery v1.25.0
google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1
```

There is a piece of retrying logic for storage write API that detects error messages on our server-side. We notice the response time of storage write API becomes longer after retrying, as a result, OOM is happening on our server. We also tried to increase the request timeout to 30 seconds, and most of those requests could not be completed within it.

How to handle the error server_shutting_down correctly?

### Update 02/08/2022

The default stream of managedwrite API is used in our server. And `server_shutting_down` error comes up periodically. And this issue happened on `02/04/2022 12:00 PM UTC` and the default stream of managedwrite API works well for over one month.

Here is one wrapper function of `appendRow` and we log the cost time of this function.

```golang
func (cl *GBOutput) appendRows(ctx context.Context,datas [][]byte, schema *gbSchema) error {
    var result *managedwriter.AppendResult
    var err error
    if cl.schema != schema {
        cl.schema = schema
        result, err = cl.managedStream.AppendRows(ctx, datas, managedwriter.UpdateSchemaDescriptor(schema.descriptorProto))
    } else {
        result, err = cl.managedStream.AppendRows(ctx, datas)
    }
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = result.GetResult(ctx)
    return err
}
```

When the error `server_shutting_down` comes up, the cost time of this function could be several hundred seconds. It is so weird, and it seems to there is no way to handle the timeout of `appendRow`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the "raw" [v1 storage API](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/apiv1), or the [managedwriter](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/managedwriter)?  I ask because managedwriter should handle stream reconnection automatically.  Are you simply observing connection closes periodically, or something about your retry traffic induces the closes?

The interesting question is how to deal with in-flight appends for which you haven't yet received an acknowledgement back (or the ack ended in failure).  If you're using offsets, you should be able to re-send the append without risk of duplication.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have updated my question and try to answer your question.

Comment: Since the `default stream` is used in our case, there is no need to handle the offset of the message. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The `default steam` mode works well on our server one month later, until 02/04/2022 12:00 PM UTC, the `server_shutting_down` error comes up on our server-side. Is there any bigquery server upgrade around that time? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Per the GCP support guy,

> The issue is hit once 10MB has been sent over the connection, regardless of how long it takes or how much is inflight at that time. The BigQuery Engineering team has identified the root cause and the fix would be rolled out by Friday, Feb 11th, 2022.